# Google Cloud NL API term/classification quality and batch processing on Traditional Chinese (zh-Hant) data

Tags: chinese-locale, google-cloud-nl

I've tested Google Cloud NL API v1.0 these days. I mainly use Traditional Chinese(a.k.a. zh-Hant) data. After the testing, I find the quality is not satisfactory, classification is not right, too many one-character terms (many of them should be stop words), the worst quality is for unknown word recognition.

Also, some analysis methods (e.g. entity-sentimental) don't support zh-Hant (that I can only use 'en' to run zh-Hant data, pitty).

Does anyone know if NL API provides any way, e.g. set configuration, set parameters, or run some process, so as to improve training result?

Does anyone actually have experience on using NL API generated result to add some value-added feature on a business product or service?

Also, if I want to feed high-volume data, is there a library or SDK, that I can use to write code to carry out batch-in-batch-out processing?